# How to Program a Drone Equipped with MAMBA MK4 Card to Execute a Flight Path Shaped Like an "L"

Tags: controller, dronekit-python, tello-drone, flightpath

I have a drone equipped with the MAMBA MK4 card and I'm trying to implement a specific flight pattern where it ascends, moves in the shape of an "L", and then lands. I've been researching various resources but haven't found a clear solution on how to program this flight path.

Could someone provide guidance or point me in the right direction on how to achieve this? Specifically, I'm looking for suggestions on programming techniques, algorithms, or libraries that could help me accomplish this task with the MAMBA MK4 card. Any code snippets or examples demonstrating how to implement such a flight path would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!